# No Docusign Admin on live docusign account

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

Error are coming on live integration key of docusign

Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code [400] with response Body: O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:5:"error";s:16:"consent_required";}

I was faced issue on demo docusign then i was enable SSO for my DocuSign organization on demo Docusign
Then solved this issue(Error) and working properly  on demo docusign .
Because there was Docusign Admin to enable SSO.

But Docusign Admin not available on live docusign account.

How to solved this Error on live Docusign

Error s:5:"error";s:16:"consent_required";

I have done already contact with support team

Answer (score 0):

In order to grant consent, you'll either need to do an [Individual Consent workflow](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-individual-consent/) for each user, or [contact the Sales team](https://www.docusign.com/contact-sales) to purchase the Admin module.

A more in-depth look at the JWT Consent options is available on the DocuSign blog - https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/oauth-jwt-granting-consent

The short answer is that Individual Consent is always available, but requires action by each individual user (Access the consent URL, authenticate, grant consent). Admin Consent is only available if you have the Admin module and a claimed domain, but allows an Organization Admin to grant consent on behalf of everyone under that claimed domain.

Answer (score 0):

Is it perhaps because the DocuSign user you use to log into the live system is not (yet) an administrator.